# Convert French Date to English Date C#

Tags: c#, datetime, date-conversion

I have object that contains french date and i want to vert it to english date
Exp: from 21/01/1990 00:00:00 to 1990-01-21 00:00:00
This my code to convert the date but didn't work because the output is `21/01/1990 00:00:00`, meaning it didn't convert the date.

```
 if (obj.DATE_OPTIN.Equals("00/00/0000 00:00"))
      obj.DATE_OPTIN = Convert.ToDateTime(obj.DATE_OPTIN_ORGANISATEUR).ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm'");
```

Where `DATE_OPTIN` is a string value.

Comment: It's always helpful that as well as saying "it didn't work" that you show the output you got or the full text of any exception that occurred.

Comment: Thanks for your response the output is 21/01/1990 00:00:00 that mean didn't convert the date

Comment: What type is `DATE_OPTIN`?

Comment: DATE_OPTIN is a string

Comment: Your conversion is conditional to the input matching exactly the string value `"00/00/0000 00:00"`, which probably prevents the conversion from happening given any other string value. Did you mean for it to match a pattern instead?

Comment: My guess is that's the magic string that signals the date was not set. In that case, OP wants the property to be set to a culture-adjusted version of the other input (`DATE_OPTIN_ORGANISATEUR`) instead. This whole problem reeks of bad data modeling, though.

Comment: yes i wanted to match it with a specfic pattern

Comment: string.Equals is the wrong tool for that. You could use a regex, but really you want to get an actual `DateTime` value as early as possible and avoid doing string manipulations for this. How about `if (DateTime.TryParseExact(...))` instead? Then you get a `DateTime` and you can call `.ToString` to format it as per your needs.

Comment: The answer below is the best way to go - but when I tested your code I got an exception "Cannot find a matching quote character for the character '''." - there is an extra single quote after mm - once removed the output is "1990-01-21T00:00" - to get what you asked for use ".ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");"

Answer (score 5):

You should convert it to a `DateTime` first specifying it's a french format and then display it as an english data by specifying the culture in the `DateTime.ToString` method.

You should have something like this:

```cs
using System.Globalization;

var frenchDateString = "21/01/1990 00:00:00";

Console.WriteLine($"French format: {frenchDateString}");

var dateTime = DateTime.Parse(frenchDateString, new CultureInfo("fr-FR"));
var englishDateString = dateTime.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-EN"));

Console.WriteLine($"English format: {englishDateString}");
```

To adapt your code to any culture, you can check this to find your culture code: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/rest-services/common-parameters-and-types/supported-culture-codes

Comment: Thanks but the output is 1/21/1990 12:00:00 AM and what i want is "01-21-1990 12:00:00"

Comment: Then you need specify a custom format. The output displayed here is the default english culture.
You can take a look at the following documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: @taniiit once you have a `DateTime` value for the input (use `DateTime.TryParseExact` to conditionally match a given pattern/format), just use `.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss")` and you're good to go.